# jquery auto compute product of two value from text inputs

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

I have two input boxes, let's name them as txt_qty and txt_price.
What I want to do is to auto compute the product of the two values and place it
in a another text input.

jQuery code:

```
$('.toAdd').live('change', function() {
  var total = 0;

  $('.toAdd').each(function () {
    var v = $(this).val();
    total *= Number(v);
  });

  $('#total_amount').val(total);
});
```

supposing txt_qty and txt_price has a class 'toAdd' and the product container has an id of 'total_amount'.

the above code works only on ADDING the two values, making

```
total += Number(v);
```

but when i made it as

```
total *= Number(v);
```

it doesn't work. what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

total = 0 at start, when you do *= at the first time, the result is 0..

If you have two input, do that :

```
var total = parseInt($('#txt_qty').val()) * parseInt($('#txt_price').val());
```